# What's the equivalent of `grpc.WithPerRPCCredentials` in C++?

Tags: c++, authentication, grpc, grpc-c++

We have some Go code which uses JWT as per RPC credentials with gRPC. I'm trying to implement a client in C++, but I can't figure out what the equivalent of the `grpc.WithPerRPCCredentials` dial option is in C++. The Go code is like this:

```golang
type claims struct {
    claims map[string]string
    secure bool
}

func (c claims) GetRequestMetadata(ctx context.Context, a ...string) (map[string]string, error) {
    return c.claims, nil
}

func (c claims) RequireTransportSecurity() bool {
    return c.secure
}

fn connect() {
    clms := claims{
        claims: make(map[string]string),
        secure: !c.insecure,
    }
    clms.claims["token"] = ourJWT;
    conn, err := grpc.DialContext(context.Background(), addr, grpc.WithPerRPCCredentials(clms))
}
```

What's the equivalent way in C++ to create credentials which attaches a JWT to each request?

Comment: [This](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth/#using-google-token-based-authentication)?

Comment: I'm not trying to authenticate with a Google service, so I don't think GoogleDefaultCredentials helps.

Answer (score 0):

The way to make a Credentials which adds metadata to each request is to use the `MetadataCredentialsPlugin` documented at https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth/#extending-grpc-to-support-other-authentication-mechanisms.